# Weird behaviour of ListView which is under a TabBarView flutter

Tags: android, listview, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an app that looks like an WhatsApp clone, it has 3 tabs which contain different ListViews and other Widgets. So, the first tab is a `ListView` that displays a list of all the chats of the user. I have the chat feature working correctly with firestore.

Child of the first `TabBarView` is a `ListView` which displays the thumbnails, names and last messages for all the users. The problem is even though the widget is loading data correctly from firestore. The ListView is blank for some reason. I'm sure that it has all the correct data. When I switch tabs though and switch back to the first tab the `ListView` shows chats just for a second then it disappears. I have no idea why this is happening, please Help!

Here is the `ListView` widget that displays chats:

```
import 'package:classroom_app/Services/app_state.dart';
import 'package:classroom_app/Services/app_events.dart';
import 'package:classroom_app/Widgets/classroom_app.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userId;

  ChatList(@required this.userId);

  @override
  _ChatListState createState() => _ChatListState();
}

class _ChatListState extends State<ChatList> {
  Widget buildRow(BuildContext context, ChatItem chat) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: 100.0,
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Image.network(
              chat.photoUrl,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              chat.userName,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
            ),
            /*Text(chat.displayMessage,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0, color: Colors.grey)),*/
          ],
        ),
        /*Text(
          chat.unseenCount.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, background: Paint()),
        ),*/
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Widget oldWidget) {
    print(ClassroomApp.of(context).chat.currentState.listOfUserChats.toString());
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ClassroomApp.of(context).chat.dispatch(GetAllConversations(widget.userId));
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: ClassroomApp.of(context).chat.state,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            if(snapshot.data.listOfUserChats == [] || snapshot.data.listOfUserChats == null) {
              return Center(child: Text('You don\'t have any chats. Try adding a Classmate.'),);
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildRow(context, snapshot.data.listOfUserChats[index]),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.listOfUserChats.length,
              );
            }
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
        },
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my homepage widget which contians the `TabBarView`.

```
import 'package:classroom_app/Services/app_state.dart';
import 'package:classroom_app/Widgets/chat_list.dart';
import 'package:classroom_app/Widgets/classroom_app.dart';
import 'package:classroom_app/Services/app_events.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum UserOptions { AddClassmate, Settings, SignOut }

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.userAuth})
      : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final AuthenticationState userAuth;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> appBarTabs = [
    Tab(text: 'CHATS'),
    Tab(text: 'LECTURES'),
    Tab(text: 'DOUBTS'),
  ];

  String _userName;

  TabController _tabController;
  TextEditingController _editingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: appBarTabs.length);
    _editingController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.
        bottom: TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: appBarTabs,
          isScrollable: false,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ChatList(widget.userAuth.user.uid),
          ),
          Center(child: Text('This is lectures view.')),
          Center(child: Text('This is doubts view.')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've added a GIF, to show the behaviour of `ListView`

[image: gif]

I'm also adding code for the `chatBloc` component as well as the `ClassroomApp` InheritedWidget

```
class ChatBloc extends Bloc<ChatEvent, ChatState> {
  final ChatService _chatService = ChatService();

  @override
  ChatState get initialState => ChatState(null, null);

  @override
  Stream<ChatState> mapEventToState(
      ChatState currentState, ChatEvent event) async* {
    if (event is StartConversation) {
      _chatService.startNewConversation(event.senderId, event.recieverName);

      yield ChatState(
          await _chatService.getAllMessagesByUserId(event.senderId), null);
    }

    if (event is GetAllConversations) {
      List<ChatItem> chatList =
          await _chatService.getAllMessagesByUserId(event.userId);

      yield ChatState(chatList, null);
    }
  }
}
```

ClassroomApp InheritedWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:classroom_app/Services/bloc_serviec.dart';

class ClassroomApp extends InheritedWidget {
  final AuthBloc auth = AuthBloc();
  final ChatBloc chat = ChatBloc();

  ClassroomApp({Widget child}) : super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;

  static ClassroomApp of(BuildContext context) =>
    context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(ClassroomApp);
}
```

Comment: can you explain how list view is blank or disappears after a second? Perhaps a few screenshots will help. Also, check the logs if there is an exception.

Comment: @UmairM I've added a gif, check it out.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what's happening here but can you try using `defaultTabController` as in this [example](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/tabs) and ditch `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` as well

Comment: Please include other dart classes as well.

Comment: I think the issue is to do with your stream `ClassroomApp.of(context).chat.state`. Can you post the code for how this stream is set?

Comment: @JordanDavies this app uses `Bloc` patter and the `flutter_bloc` packages to manage state and business logic, I'm adding the code for those now.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm experiencing a similar issue. On first run data is downloaded then retrieved from database, but first tab is blank unless I reopen the page. Other tabs are populated like yours.